# Colour bars based on values in pandas dataframe when using plotnine

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, ggplot2, plotnine

I am trying to build a waterfall chart using plotnine.  I would like to colour the starting and ending bars as grey (ideally I want to specify hexadecimal colours), increases as green and decreases as red.

Below is some sample data and my current plot.  I am trying to set `fill` to the pandas column `colour`, but the bars are all black.  I have also tied putting `fill` in the `geom_segment`, but this does not work either.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
df['label'] = ('A','B','C','D','E')
df['percentile'] = (10)*5
df['value'] = (100,80,90,110,110)
df['yStart'] = (0,100,80,90,0)
df['barLabel'] = ('100','-20','+10','+20','110')
df['labelPosition'] = ('105','75','95','115','115')
df['colour'] = ('grey','red','green','green','grey')

p = (ggplot(df, aes(x=np.arange(0,5,1), xend=np.arange(0,5,1), y='yStart',yend='value',fill='colour'))
    + theme_light(6)
    + geom_segment(size=10)
    + ylab('value')
    + scale_y_continuous(breaks=np.arange(0,141,20), limits=[0,140], expand=(0,0))
)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Based on teunbrand's comment of changing `fill` to `color`, I have the following.  How do I specify the actual colour, preferably in hexadecimal format?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with plotnine but in R ggplot2 a `geom_segment()` has a `colour` but not a `fill` aesthetic. You might try replacing `fill='colour'` with `colour='colour'`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works, but I don't get the colours I want.  The bars that are meant to be grey are green with a label 'grey' , bars that are meant to be green are red with a label 'green' and the bars that are meant to be red are blue with a label 'red'.  I will post an edit.  But it you are able to submit and answer with that fix, I will make as accepted.  Thank you so much

Comment: Again from what I know of R ggplot2, you'll likely need to have a `scale_colour_identity()` if the content of your colour column are literal colours and not something that has to be mapped to colours.

Comment: You can also use the `scale_colour_manual()` function to specify the exact colors (accepts hexadecimals) to the `values` argument that correspond to each label in the provided data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question off, credit goes to teunbrand in the comments for the solution.

`geom_segment()` has a `colour` aesthetic but not a `fill` aesthetic.  Replace `fill='colour'` with `colour='colour'`.

Plotnine will use default colours for the bars.  Use `scale_color_identity()` if the contents of the `DataFrame` column are literal colours, or `scale_colour_manual()` to manually specify a tuple or list of colours.  Both forms accept hexadecimal colours.